# windows x64 assembler?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit

I recently upgraded to a 64 bit computer from a 32 bit. I have used masm32 for x86 assembly previously. My computer can run 32 bit processes, but I would prefer to use all of my computers capability and write x64 assembly programs. I do not want to have to install extra things (like ide's) to make an assembler run. What assembler should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is [MASM for x64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hb5z4sxd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) what you're looking for?

If you want to avoid a Visual Studio installation, there's [YASM](http://yasm.tortall.net), [NASM](http://www.nasm.us), and [FASM](http://www.flatassembler.net).

All of the above are mentioned in [Intel's Introduction to x64 Assembly](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-x64-assembly/).

Comment: I believe I have to install visual studio to use masm

Comment: There's a standalone MASM32 package (AFAIK, unofficial, collected from the various SDKs and DDKS piece by piece).

Comment: Edited answer to include non-VS options. However, as mentioned by Alexey, MASM does exist in standalone form.

Comment: @Alexey Frunze MASM32 not 64.